# XPath Axes - Replace 'text' value of child nodes under a parent with parent node's attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath, axes

I'm trying to apply the XPath to the XML file with structure below:

**XPath: /root/tour/round/event/parent::round/@name**

The expected output is:

```
final
semifinal
semifinal
quarterfinal
quarterfinal
quarterfinal
quarterfinal
round3
```

But I'm not getting the above output, instead getting like this:

```
final
semifinal
quarterfinal
round3
```

I would really appreciate any help to get the expected output.

**XML File**

```
<root>
    <tour>
        <round name="final">
            <event>Test</event>
        </round>
        <round name="semifinal">
            <event>Test</event>
            <event>Test</event>
        </round>
        <round name="quarterfinal">
            <event>Test</event>
            <event>Test</event>
            <event>Test</event>
            <event>Test</event>
        </round>
        <round name="round3">
            <event>Test</event>
            <event>Test</event>
            <event>Test</event>
            <event>Test</event>
        </round>
    </tour>
</root>
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Are you using code? XSLT? We need to have that context in order to be able to help you.

Comment: You can't do this with a single XPath 1.0 expression. An XPath 1.0 expression can produce a nodeset, which is a distinct set of nodes. Since there are only 4 @name nodes in the document, that is everything that is selected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put loop with your XPATH condition:

```
for $eachEvent in //event return $eachEvent/parent::round/@name
```

Comment: Thanks @navin. I'm looking for plain XPath, do you think this is possible using plain XPath?

Comment: This is valid and plain XPath 2.0.

Comment: Then give us more information on what query processor you're using. Probably it's not supporting XPath 2.0, but this is a valid answer to the question you asked. But probably this will not be possible in XPath 1.0, you will have to loop over the events and construct that output in the programming language used around.